# Applying spatial reference when using XY Table To Point with ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I have a series of CSV files that I need to convert to point feature classes. I have the following code :

```
# Convert CSV file to raster
import arcpy
workspace = "Y://DEM250m//CSV_Points"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace # Set environment settings
mycsvs = arcpy.ListFiles("*1980-2010.csv") # Access all historical data

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference()

# Convert CSV to point featureclass
out_table = "Y://DEM250m//CSV_Points//Historical"
for i in mycsvs:
    arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(
        workspace + "//" + i,
        out_table + "//" + i, 
        'Latitude',
        'Longitude',
        'Elevation',
        arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
        )
```

I have tried many variations of the following:

```
arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
arcpy.SpatialReference(r'c:/DEM/dem.prj')
arcpy.SpatialReference('WGS 1984')
```

It never seems to want to project my csv data correctly (it always seems to show up in the middle of the ocean around the equator). I have checked what a lot of other people have posted about here before and tried those solutions, but they never seem to work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

I have added an image of what the relevant CSV columns look like.

[image]

Comment: The tool's help page talks about *When the Z Field parameter is specified, the default coordinate system also includes the WGS 1984 vertical coordinate system. If the z-values are not in meters, modify the coordinate system to use the correct elevation unit.*. Most probably your `sr` definition is incomplete. You can try `arcpy.SpatialReference(4326, 3855)`.

Comment: Hi fatih_dur, I just tried your recommendation and it still threw my points in the middle of the ocean. Also, the z values are in meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code where you are supplying your coordinates in the sequence of Latitude (Y) then Longitude (X). Look at the [tool's help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm) and you we see that the tool requires Longitude (X) then Latitude (Y).

My test data was a folder of just one csv so you'll need to adjust your code accordingly, but this worked for me:

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
workspace = r"C:\Scratch"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace # Set environment settings    
mycsvs = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv") # Access all historical data    
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

# Convert CSV to point featureclass
out_table = r"C:\Scratch"
for i in mycsvs:
    arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(workspace + "//" + i,out_table + "//test2.shp",'Longitude','Latitude','Elevation',sr)
```